# How to specify the date format of column in Rscript

Tags: r

[I have tried this. But its giving me error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51vyA.png)

```
Datecreated<-c('Created Time')
```

I will get this data from cloud using APIs. I need to define the format of this Created Time column as d-mon-yy

For example- 18-Nov-17

How can I achiEve this. I am new to R.

Any help woud be appreciated.

Comment: format would be `as.Date(date, "%d-%b-%y")`

Comment: here date means do I need to put Created Time ?

Comment: Your `'Created Time'` is a string.  It is not clear

Comment: Yes when I getting Created Time from cloud, Its datatype is  String. Now how can I convert it to date and then required format?

Comment: If it is an object in R, then `get(Datecreated)` i.e. `v1 <- 'c1';
 c1 <- 10;
 get(v1)#
[1] 10`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve] ... then **edit your question!**

Comment: @akrun I have posted the screens shot in my question. once check please.

Comment: Hmm, you have an object with spaces.  Try with backquotes and also it is not clear

Comment: Try with backquotes means? I didnot get you @akrun

Comment: It works for me.  May be your question is different.  I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is showing you assign the string ‘created time’ to the variable `Datecreated`. I’m not sure where or how you’re getting your data but I’m assuming that is your issue. Once you have your data you can use akrun’s answer of `as.Date(column, “%d-%b-%y”)`

```
MyDates <- c(“17-Jan-16”, “6-Feb-17”)
FormattedDates <- as.Date(MyDates, “%d-%b-%y”)
```